# How to compare text with regex which is in variable?

Tags: regex, bash

I have the following in input.txt:

```
EA06\\?\.LFRFLB\\?\..*
```

I want to know if this pattern match with the following string:

```
EA06.LFRFLB.SHELLO
```

Then I coded:

```
MY_STRING="EA06.LFRFLB.SHELLO"
REGEX=$(cat input.txt) # EA06\\?\.LFRFLB\\?\..*

if [[ "${MY_STRING}" =~ "${REGEX}" ]]; then
  echo "FOUND"
else
 echo "NOT FOUND"
fi

if [[ "${MY_STRING}" =~ EA06\\?\.LFRFLB\\?\..* ]]; then
  echo "FOUND"
else
 echo "NOT FOUND"
fi
```

Result:

```
NOT FOUND
FOUND
```

Whats is going wrong here? Why the first if does not match correctly? What is the best way to solve it?

Comment: Shouldn't there be quotes around the output of `cat input.txt`?

Comment: Why would it, the strings are different ?

Comment: @Jidder My brain is hurting too much today. hehe... I should keep my head out of this sort of shell scripting stuff for a while ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you quoted the variable on the RHS of the binary operator `=~` which causes the variable replacement to be treated as literal text and not as a regex.  You need to say:

```
if [[ "${MY_STRING}" =~ ${REGEX} ]]; then
```

Quoting from the manual:

> ```
>    An additional binary operator, =~, is available, with the  same  prece‐
>    dence  as  ==  and !=.  When it is used, the string to the right of the
>    operator is considered  an  extended  regular  expression  and  matched
>    accordingly  (as  in  regex(3)).   The  return value is 0 if the string
>    matches the pattern, and 1 otherwise.  If  the  regular  expression  is
>    syntactically  incorrect,  the conditional expression's return value is
>    2.  If the shell option nocasematch is enabled, the match is  performed
>    without  regard  to the case of alphabetic characters.  Any part of the
>    pattern may be quoted to force it to be  matched  as  a  string.
> ```

Note the last line in particular:

> Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force it to be  matched  as  a  string.

Comment: @JohnDoe Note that the usual advice to always quote parameter expansions does not apply inside `[[ ... ]]`, since different rules apply. In particular, such parameter expansions are not subject to filename generation or word splitting